# My employee keeps calling in with medical issues

Tags: united-states, human-resources, government, texas

My employee (in Southeast Texas, workplace is a municipal government entity) keeps calling in with medical issues and offers no proof of issue. No doctors note, no info regarding what the issue is. It's been 3 weeks since they reported to work for 1 day. This employee has exhausted all compensable time, and has previously received a written warning for absenteeism from my predecessor.

How do I ask them to justify their absences?

Comment: Welcome to SE. in its current state this is not a question - please check the help center to see what questions are on topic here. Note that this is a strict Q&A site not a forum for general discussion

Comment: Where in the world are you? There are no global rules and regulations for sick days, sick notes or anything of that kind. We need more information to help you.

Comment: Is it company policy that they are required to offer information or proof of a medical issue?

Comment: What is your role?  What are your company’s rules on absences and your local laws (where are you?).  Depending on policy, law, and custom this may be fine or it may not be.

Comment: We still don't know where are you, and what is your desired outcome.

Comment: And why not just fire them exactly?

Comment: SE Texas municipal government? This is a political question, not a simple employer question. If the person in question does not have political connections, then fire. Otherwise, check with their political patrons to see what actions they will allow.

Comment: **How do I ask them to justify their absences?** - You can try, but I don't believe they have any legal requirement to tell you. If it were me, I'd ask my HR department how to best handle this.

Comment: @DavidR - You have not addressed all the questions proposed to you. By editing your questions and clarifying your question it might be reopened

Comment: Voting to reopen: This is not a question about "company-specific regulations", it is a general question of how to handle a situation that can happen in any company, and it may benefit from suggestions that apply regardless of a particular organization or setting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This one's easy: you go straight to your HR department and say "how do I handle this?"

HR is not the employee's friend but then in this case, you don't want to be the employee's friend.

Answer (score 8):

To second the accepted response, escalating this to HR immediately seems the most reasonable (and necessary) course of action at this point.

To educate yourself, you might also want to review any internal resources from HR that deal with policies related to medical leave, including the **Employee Handbook**.

The HR policy on medical leave should stipulate the maximum number of days that an employee can call in sick and charge sick leave *without* medical documentation. For leave beyond those days, the employee MUST provide medical proof (e.g. doctor's note, etc.). If the employee is out of compliance, it becomes HR's problem.

As one possibility, the employee may have to request FMLA leave if/when their other accruals are exhausted.

HR will probably have a talk with you about being two weeks too late bringing this to their attention, but better 2 weeks late than 2 months late...

HR may request you to provide evidence of any and all documented (email, text) communication between you and the employee to which the employee failed to respond, so it may be wise to gather/print all that in advance and come to HR prepared. Good luck!